# Strange certificate message

Tags: ssl, browser, https, certificate

at the **same**(=identical) youtube url I get **three** different messages (see attached picture). Video is available for IE and Chrome. Most puzzling to me is that I have a private key of certificate for the server (IE version). I probably do not understand something.

[image: strange certificate info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internet Explorer**: Microsoft Family Safety is known to intercept SSL connecitons. That's why you see the certificate for google signed by Microsoft Family Safety and because the private key for the certificate is needed for SSL interception you see that the private key is available on the computer.

**Firefox**: Firefox uses the system proxy settings and thus is also subject to SSL interception. But Firefox does not use the systems CA store and thus the CA for Microsoft Family Safety is not trusted by Firefox. That's why you get the error.

**Chrome**: Chrome uses the systems CA store and should also use the systems proxy setting by default. But the picture shows that Chrome gets the original certificate. The only explanation I have for this is that this snapshot was either done on a different computer with different setup or that the settings of Chrome were changed so that it does not use the system settings any more.

Comment: Thanks,  Answers:  
1/ Snapshots are from identical computer and from one(=the same) session.  
2/ Yes, after Chrome-reset-configuration I see "Microsoft Family". 

**Question**:  
I still do not understand the behavior of Firefox, see ** [description](http://postimg.org/image/ro8nsf8b7/). **

Comment: @LeosPilny: might be a configuration thing which sites gets SSL intercepted and which not. And Verisign and Geotrust are different CA. More question please at superuser.com because none of this is related to programming.